# How to use Spark with neo4j?

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

I am a beginner for Neo4j.
Recently i was creating graphes by loading the **csv** and creating in the main time nodes and their relationships.

now my boss ,who wants a scalable solution,give me a Spark project and want me to process or load the java-pair-rdd and create a graph based on it.

so how to use spark with neo4j ?

**Update**:

I found [Cypher for Apache Spark](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) but it's steel in **Beta** version and the Build dosen't succeed  on windows 10.

Comment: Search previous questions for how others are doing it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark+neo4j?sort=votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cypher for apache spark**

I find a way on how to create a graph from a Spark data-frame and store it in Neo4J.

You can see [my answer on how to run CAPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417454/run-cypher-for-apache-spark-examples-caps?answertab=active#tab-top) for who is interested about this question.

**Neo4j-spark-connector**

for this second solution , i find a new article in [medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-graph-data-pipeline-with-zeppelin-spark-and-neo4j-8b6b83f4fb70) talking about how to connect spark ,neo4j and the zeppelin notebook