# Run Cypher for Apache Spark examples (CAPS)

Tags: scala, maven, neo4j, cypher

I know that this a wide question, but it would be helpful  for **neo4j** users those who aren't in a field of *scala* programming.

I am in need to use [Cypher for Apache Spark Project](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) in order to create a Neo4j graph from a data-frame and then storing it into Neo4j.

I tried to integrate the project in eclipse, but with no luck , i get a [wired error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398331/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-numberformatexception-not-a-version-9), so i couldn't get the help of an IDE.

> What i need is a way to run the [**Scala example
>   classes**](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark/tree/master/spark-cypher-examples/src/main/scala/org/opencypher/spark/examples)
>   of this maven project ??

In [another scala maven project](https://github.com/opencypher/caps-examples) a contributor give me this cmd :

```
mvn scala:run -DmainClass=org.opencypher.example.HelloCypher
```

I tried to trick it, but the trick dosen't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to run the *Cypher for Apache Spark Project* .

For me what i need is the ***InputDataFrameExample***,(which creates a graph from a dataframe and then store it in neo4j).

## Without an IDE

The unique environnement that works for me is **Linux**(Ubuntu 18 for me) , in **windows 10** the project is simply dosen't work without an ide , you can find why [in this issue](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark/issues/564#10) .

The steps to make it run in **ubuntu** are :

1)Download [CAPS-Cypher for Apache Spark](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark)

2) run `mvn clean install` in the project folder

3) start your neo4j , run `service neo4j start`

4) add this code(config of the connection to your Neo4j) to **InputDataFrameExample**(add only what is missing):

```
import org.opencypher.spark.api.CAPSSession

import java.net.URI

import org.opencypher.spark.api.io.neo4j.Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource

import org.opencypher.spark.api.io.neo4j.Neo4jConfig

import org.opencypher.okapi.api.graph.GraphName



 val session: CAPSSession = CAPSSession.local()

 val boltWriteURI: URI = new URI("bolt://localhost:7687")

 val neo4jWriteConfig: Neo4jConfig = new Neo4jConfig(boltWriteURI, "neo4j", Some("your_Neo4j_password"), true)

 val neo4jResult: Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource = new Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource(neo4jWriteConfig)(session)

 val neo4jResultName: GraphName = new GraphName("neo4jgraph");

  neo4jResult.store(neo4jResultName, yourGraph);
```

5) run `mvn scala:run -DmainClass=org.opencypher.spark.examples.DataFrameInputExample` inside of the spark-cypher-examples

6) finally you could point your browser to

> localhost:7474 and run the cypher query
>   `match(n) return n` to see if that works or not.

## With an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA)

IntelliJ IDEA can run the project in the two environments (LINUX & WINDOWS)

these are the steps in order to run **CAPS** with IntelliJ IDEA:

1) [download IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download) and install it.

2) Open IntelliJ IDEA click on Configure -> Click on Plugins -> Click on Install JetBrains Plugins -> Search for Scala -> Click on install button => this will install the scala plugin needed by the project

3) Download [CAPS-Cypher for Apache Spark](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark)

4) Import your project in intelliJ IDEA (click on import project >external resources and choose maven then next  until the project is open)

**important :** you need to have **jdk 8**

5) add this code(config of the connection to your Neo4j) to **InputDataFrameExample**(add only what is missing):

```
import org.opencypher.spark.api.CAPSSession

import java.net.URI

import org.opencypher.spark.api.io.neo4j.Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource

import org.opencypher.spark.api.io.neo4j.Neo4jConfig

import org.opencypher.okapi.api.graph.GraphName



 val session: CAPSSession = CAPSSession.local()

 val boltWriteURI: URI = new URI("bolt://localhost:7687")

 val neo4jWriteConfig: Neo4jConfig = new Neo4jConfig(boltWriteURI, "neo4j", Some("your_Neo4j_password"), true)

 val neo4jResult: Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource = new Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource(neo4jWriteConfig)(session)

 val neo4jResultName: GraphName = new GraphName("neo4jgraph");

  neo4jResult.store(neo4jResultName, yourGraph);
```

6) **start your neo4j service**: `service neo4j start` and `bin\neo4j.bat start` on windows

7) back to IntelliJ IDEA  and run the class (Inputdataframe)  as **Application**

8) finally you could point your browser to

> localhost:7474 and run the cypher query
>   `match(n) return n`

to see if that works or not.

[image: neo4j graph result]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much in the same boat. I have been able to build the project. You will need to make some changes in the POM.xml. Defaults did not work for me

I did below:

1. Create a new Maven project
2. Registered all okapi artifact dependencies and dependencies for other modules such as spark-cypher
3. Add Scala nature to the project
4. Did a maven build and maven install from eclipse
5. Build was success

Post that I included org package under src/main/scala

1. Ran CustomDataFrameInputExample.scala as Scala application. It ran fine.
2. Still struggling while reading from CAPS local session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for you reply. actually i leaved eclipse and i used Intellij IDEA instead

Comment: you can ask questions on neo4j slack it is there where i get help also you can make an issue in github they answer quickley

Comment: hi @Neeraj did you know how to load a C.S.V into a Data-frame in this project ?